# Trying to collect heap dump from kubernetes POD

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In one of our environment, few Kubernetes PODs are restarting very frequently and we are trying to find the reason for that by collecting heap and thread dumps.
Any idea of how to collect those if PODs are failing very often?

Comment: Instead of relying on PV path, I would instead go with glowroot which can be deployed as a pod and serves you as central heap analysis.
https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot

Comment: I would sugget to implant a logging system to your application, you should use stackdriver to store the logs, or even a elasticsearch with kibana. Are you able to change the application to make this modification?

Answer (score 1):

Yoh can try mounting a host volume to the pod,and than configure your app to dump in the path which is mapped to the host volume. Or any other way to save the heap dump in persitent place

Comment: I prefer central heap dump such as glowroot instead of this so its much easier to handle especially in clouds where node access is restricted.